# Using better-sqlite3 in an Angular + Electron app: Module parse failed: Unexpected character

Tags: node.js, angular, sqlite, electron, better-sqlite3

In my [Angular + Electron app](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) I'm trying to install some sqlite library in order to read contents from an sqlite database file.

I've installed [better-sqlite3](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3) using:

```
npm install --save better-sqlite3 
npm install --save-dev @types/better-sqlite3
```

And I've tried to use it doing:

```
import * as sqlite from 'better-sqlite3';

// ...

const myDb = sqlite('/path/to/file.sqlite');
```

However when the application builds it fails with:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/better_sqlite3.node 1:0
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
>   configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this
>   binary file) ERROR in ./node_modules/integer/build/integer.node 1:0
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
>   configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this
>   binary file)

It looks like I'm not the first experiencing this issue when using Electron. Infact, the issue has been discussed [here](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/issues/349) and and [here](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/issues/126) however I couldn't find a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`?

```
npm i @angular-builders/custom-webpack --save-dev
```

in your angular.json file, set this under your architect:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./angular.webpack.js"
      },
```

and then add a custom config file angular.webpack.js at the root of your project:

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    'better-sqlite3': "require('better-sqlite3')"
  }
};
```